# Is there an Objective-C/C libary that can do code syntax highlighting?

Tags: objective-c, c, codehighlighter

Of course, I don't actually need it to highlight anything, I'll take care of that, however, it would be great if there would be a library that can parse text and can in an abstract manner tell me which words should I highlight and how should I treat them (as functions, vars, etc). I think (not sure) Clang would be an option, but seems really heavy duty for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes libclang is the way to go.

**Watch [this video](http://devimages.apple.com/llvm/videos/Libclang.mov)** (captured at 2010 LLVM Developers' Meeting) for more info, which presents the libclang API and should give you a really good overview of how to use the API.

You may probably be interested in [the others videos here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CompilerTools/Conceptual/LLVMCompilerOverview/_index.html) too.

Comment: Wow, that video is really great. Clang seems to be the way to go!